# В Laravel связать три таблицы. Для продукта выводить характеристики и их значения

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mvc

Есть интернет-витрина с продуктом, характеристиками продуктов и значениями характеристик.

Все лежит в отдельных таблицах products, specifications, specification_values. Подскажите, как правильно создать связующую таблицу для этих трех таблиц и делать выборку Характеристика - Значение для отдельного продукта?
Изначально создал таблицу product_values, в которой есть id, product_id, specification_id, value_id

Но во всех примерах и документации показывают как связать, например, product_id и specification_id
Чтоб связать три таблицы пока опыта не хватает. Прошу подсказать

Мне нужно при отображении Продукта с ID 1 показать характеристику с id 1 и значением этой характеристики с с id 1, и характеристику с id 2 и его значением с id 3. И вывести их названия.
Например, для продукта REHAU Euro 60 белый (таблица products, ID 1)
Бренд (таблица specifications, ID 1) - REHAU (таблица specification_values, ID 1)
Цвет (таблица specifications, ID 2) - белый (таблица specification_values, ID 3)
[image: Вид связующей таблицы]

Как правильно создать структуру таблицы или таблиц, как сделать связь в моделях и как правильно вывести все характеристики для товара. Спасибо

Comment: *Но во всех примерах и документации показывают как связать, например, product_id и specification_idь* Ясен пень. Связать можно по-разному. Это может быть одна связующая таблица, а может их быть и две. Всё зависит от того, как эти сущности связаны логически в рамках предметной области.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на свой собственный вопрос.

Есть паттерн по связи Сущность-Атрибут-Значение. Называется модель EAV. Иногда можно встретить мнение, что это антипаттерн. Если ищете рещение по похожей задаче, то можете посмотреть в его сторону.
Я обошелся стандартными связями в Laravel.

Я понял, что нет смысла связывать три таблицы через связующую. У значения определенной характеристики есть только одно название характеристики.
В итоге Многие-ко-многим я связал только Продукты-Значения, а уже из Значения получил название Характеристики, к которому это значение относится